# Pseudo-code examples of A*?

Tags: path-finding

I'm looking for pseudo-code examples of the A* pathfinding algorithm that actually **works**. I tried plenty of different ones where it's not really clear how to implement them at all times. Keep in mind that I'm a newbie, so if everything could be detailed, that'd be great.

Comment: I implemented [this one](http://wiki.gamegardens.com/Path_Finding_Tutorial#Pseudo-code_A.2A) not too long ago and worked for me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the pseudocode in the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm#Pseudocode) is sufficiently detailed. If you need more details and a working implementation then [A* Pathfinding for Beginners](https://gist.github.com/jcward/45afd22560939aaae5c75e68f1e57505) is a good article. It has C++ sample code with comments.

Answer (score 3):

On [my site](https://www.newarteest.com/flash/astar.html) I have an A* implementation I did in Actionscript based on [this tutorial](https://gist.github.com/jcward/45afd22560939aaae5c75e68f1e57505).

Comment: It is really good! Although, I didn't know people still use ActionScript...

Comment: ActionScript is the most common language for Flash development by far.