# Basic A star implementation tutorial

Tags: path-finding, grid

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Pseudo-code examples of A*?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/19430/pseudo-code-examples-of-a)

Hey guys Iam making a TD game and now I am stucked in implementing A star algo. I know there are many 3d party softwares but they are difficult to understand and modify. I want to make own for my game. I need a step wise programming tutorial for implementing A* OR if someone has basic snippet. I am using unity and c#.

Answer (score 2):

As for some snippets, I've written a few articles about A*.
Anyway my latest C# based A* algorithm is here: http://roy-t.nl/index.php/2011/09/24/another-faster-version-of-a-2d3d-in-c/ you can use it freely. It also links to some of the articles.

Comment: Do you give me any tutorial to implement this algorithm?